# What is considered as a "file access" on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Given that GCS pricing varies greatly depending on the storage class you use (standard, nearline, coldline), and that picking a file class is mostly determined by how frequently you'll need to access the file, what does Google Cloud Storage consider as an "*access*"? Downloading and uploading blobs seam the most obvious answers, but I was wondering if using gsutil commands [like ls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls) or operations like renaming a file would be considered as an access as well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Spend some time with the documentation so that you understand what access means. For example, there is no rename of objects. A rename is actually a copy (read and write) with a delete. Commands like `ls` list objects but do not read the contents of objects. These are different types of `access`. These types are broken down into HTTP operations such as `HEAD`, `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) for Google Cloud Storage, there are [three classes of operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class). And you will be billed depending on the storage class of the object or bucket that is being used to perform the operation.

In the example you consider, a `gsutil ls` uses the JSON API by default:

> If you access Cloud Storage through gsutil, JSON API operations are used by default

In this case this is a `storage.objects.list` operation belonging to the class A operations so you will be billed for 0.05$ per 10,000 operations in the `Standard Storage` class and for 0.10$ per 10,000 operations in the `Nearline Storage` and `Coldline Storage` class.